# Flink State TTL expiration for Collections

Tags: scala, apache-flink, flink-streaming

Thank you for taking the time to read this, I want to consult you experts on the Flink state TTL feature in Flink 1.8.0, after reading 
 this, it is still vague to me.

https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.8/dev/stream/state/state.html#state-time-to-live-ttl

I want to make sure where the TTL feature is enabled, is it on the key field or the value field. Particularly, say I have a mapState structure like this:

```
mapState = Map[String,List[String]]
e.g. val mapState = Map("haha" -> List("foo","bar")) in Scala
where "haha" is the key of the mapState and List("foo","bar") is the value
```

If I were to set a TTL of 1 minute on the mapState through the StateTtlConfig, then immediately (less than 1 minute) write to one of the values in List, say "foo".

Then after 1 minute, when the TTL fires, does the key "haha" expires or the value "bar" expires?

In other words, if it was to expire on the key, my understanding is that the mapState would remain intact

`mapState = Map("haha" -> List("foo","bar"))`

because writing to the value "foo" would reset the TTL on the key, thus the whole mapState stays the same

Another scenario is that if it was to expire on the value, the mapState would become

```
mapState = Map("haha" -> List("foo"))
```

because the value "bar" would expire after 1 minute without being accessed.

Hopefully, I made the question clear, Thank you in advance for any form of help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code for the accessing the state with TTL looks as follows:

```
<SE extends Throwable, CE extends Throwable, CLE extends Throwable, V> TtlValue<V> getWrappedWithTtlCheckAndUpdate(
        SupplierWithException<TtlValue<V>, SE> getter,
        ThrowingConsumer<TtlValue<V>, CE> updater,
        ThrowingRunnable<CLE> stateClear) throws SE, CE, CLE {
        TtlValue<V> ttlValue = getter.get();
        if (ttlValue == null) {
            return null;
        } else if (expired(ttlValue)) {
            stateClear.run();
            if (!returnExpired) {
                return null;
            }
        } else if (updateTsOnRead) {
            updater.accept(rewrapWithNewTs(ttlValue));
        }
        return ttlValue;
    }
```

The method that verifies wether the value is expired looks as below:

```
    static <V> boolean expired(@Nullable TtlValue<V> ttlValue, long ttl, long currentTimestamp) {
        return ttlValue != null && expired(ttlValue.getLastAccessTimestamp(), ttl, currentTimestamp);
    }
```

Which basically means that in this case it will check the TTL for the whole list not for separate elements. So depending on the `StateTtlConfig` the whole list will expire or the whole list will not expire.

The TTL configs that are available are `OnReadAndWrite` and `OnCreateAndWrite`. So, basically in order for this to be consistent You need to use `put()` on `MapState` if You want to update your value list.

Comment: thank you very much for responding. Based on the code and explanation you provided, my understandings is that it is the same as the "expire on Key" conceptually right in the above simple example? it is because the whole value collection is tied to one TTL no matter how many items are in it?  As a follow-up question, I guess the way to expire on individual items in the value list would be to allevate the value item into the keyspace? something like mapState = Map("haha_foo" -> 1, "haha_bar" -> 1)?

Comment: Yeap, basically the concept works as the "expire on Key". Your solution with namespaces should solve the issue and it seems to be the easiest solution. May I ask what is Your usecase ?

Comment: I had a mapstate that has more than one layer of values. e.g. MapState(String -> Map(String -> List(String))) in Scala. After running some time, the mapstate becomes so big such that it stalls the entire Flink. I want to clean it up by adding some TTL to the values. Also, I want to take advantage of the built-in TTL mechanism provided by Flink instead of writing my own cleaning logics. That's why asked the original question in the first place.

Comment: By the way, I want to confirm one thing also: the built-in TTL mechanism can only clean the "Value" in the first layer right?  i.e. the Map(String -> List(String)) as a whole in the above example, it CAN NOT go into the second layer and clean the value of the Map i.e. List(String) right? since Flink doesn't really know what data structure sare stored beyond one layer. The source code you mentioned got me thinking it can recursively traverse down whatever layers within the mapState until it reaches the "Leaf" value. i.e. List(String) in the above example. Thank you very much.